# Solve Summation of Catalan Convolution?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, summation, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

Can someone help me solve this?

> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2 k+4} 4\left(\begin{array}{c}
> 2 k+3 \\
> k
> \end{array}\right)}{k+4}
> $$
> converges.

Wolfram alpha says it converges to $1$.

But actually, I have no idea, how to solve it.

Comment: This is speculative, but perhaps you could use Stirling's approximation to bound the terms by expressions involving only elementary functions? (Specifically the formulation given in Robbins 1956 that gives explicit bounds.) That is usually what I first try when I need to bound the growth of something involving factorials (in this case constituting the binomial coefficients). I think at the very least it could be useful as a sanity check that it converges. But you might even be able to use those Stirling bounds with squeeze theorem somehow to deduce the exact limit of the sequence.

Comment: Maybe try to interpret the summand as a probability.

Answer (score 1):

Using a version of the [binomial power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Binomial_coefficients)
$$\sum_{k\geq 0}{2k+\alpha \choose k}z^k=\frac 1 {\sqrt{1-4z}}\left(\frac {1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\right)^\alpha$$
With $\alpha=3$:
$$\sum_{k\geq 0}{2k+3\choose k}z^k=\frac 1 {\sqrt{1-4z}}\left(\frac {1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\right)^3$$
Consequently
$$\sum_{k\geq 0}{2k+3\choose k}\frac{z^{k+4}}{k+4}=\int_0^z \frac {t^3} {\sqrt{1-4t}}\left(\frac {1-\sqrt{1-4t}}{2t}\right)^3dt=\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{1-4z}\right)^4}{64}$$
Evaluating at $z=\frac 1 4$:
$$\sum_{k\geq 0}{2k+3\choose k}\frac{\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{2k+8}}{k+4}=\frac{1}{64}$$
Re-arranging the terms:
$$4\sum_{k\geq 0}{2k+3\choose k}\frac{\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{2k+4}}{k+4}=1$$

Comment: Yes, I see. Just want to add some links for someone in future.

Comment: first formula can be derived with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient

Comment: Please, can you explain or give clue on 3rd step. Exactly how Integral was derived. Is it connected to harmonic series?

Comment: The first equality is by multiplying the series we had at the previous line by $z^3$ and then integrating term by term. Remember that $\int^z_0 t^{k+3}dt=\frac{z^{k+4}}{k+4}$. The second equality was obtained by Wolfram Alpha. You can verify that the derivative of the left-hand side is indeed the integrand.